# Вставка символа с нижним индексом в формулу docx

Tags: c#, ms-word

Для работы с word документом использую Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. 
Для вставки формулы делаю так

```
                        Paragraph par = sdoc.Words[позиция слова].Paragraphs.Add();
                        par.Range.Text = $"arcsin((π∙m)/bw) = arcsin((3.14∙{db1})/{db2}) = {num} ";
                        sdoc.Words[позиция слова].OMaths.Add(par.Range).OMaths.BuildUp();
```

Знаю, что для вставки значения с верхним индексом используется символ ^. Как можно реализовать вставки значения с нижним индексом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте "_" перед индексом.

∑_(n=1)^∞